# Specify database in test

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

I want to run model tests without altering my database.
I'm using a mysql database without evolutions.

Is it possible to specify a different database for my tests? Or copy the mysql schema into a memory database ?

I tried making a separate config and use it like this:

```
play test -Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf
```

without profit.

Comment: Isn't it `-Dconfig.file=application.test.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use multiple database in play application. here i am giving example for three databases in application.(prod,dev,test)

write conf file for production (in conf directory)

**prod.conf**

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver                                                                             
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/productiondatabase"  
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="postgres"
```

write conf file for develop

**dev.conf**

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver                                                                             
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/developmentdatabase"
db.default.user="postgres"
db.default.password="postgres"
```

write conf file for test

**test.conf**

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test"
db.default.user=sa
db.default.password=""
```

Now write **Global.scala** (in app directory)

```
import play.api._  
import play.api.Logger  
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory   
import java.io.File 

 object Global extends GlobalSettings {    

      override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader:     ClassLoader,mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {

    Logger.info("Application  configuration file is loading with " + mode.toString + "  mode")

    val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"${mode.toString.toLowerCase}.conf"))
    super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)

  }
}
```

$ play test => it  automatically connect to test database.

$ play run => it  automatically connect to dev database.

$ play start =>it  automatically connect to prod database.

Comment: How do I set the schema for my test db (copy from dev)?

Comment: Create database schema script(from dev or as you wish) for example mysql.sql and:
db.default.url="""jdbc:h2:mem:mysqldb;MODE=MySQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'scriptdirpath/mysql.sql' """

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using evolutions.